# Youtube API C# Error, cant post comment? What else should I do

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

```
async Task AddVideoCommentAsync(string commentToAdd, string videoID, YouTubeService youtubeService)
    {
        CommentSnippet commentSnippet = new CommentSnippet();
        commentSnippet.TextOriginal = commentToAdd;

        Comment topLevelComment = new Comment();
        topLevelComment.Snippet = commentSnippet;

        CommentThreadSnippet commentThreadSnippet = new CommentThreadSnippet();
        commentThreadSnippet.ChannelId = "UCsK0terzCGmIPAeGmW-i-VA";
        commentThreadSnippet.VideoId = videoID;
        commentThreadSnippet.TopLevelComment = topLevelComment;

        CommentThread commentThread = new CommentThread();
        commentThread.Snippet = commentThreadSnippet;

        
        CommentThreadsResource.InsertRequest insertComment = youtubeService.CommentThreads.Insert(commentThread, "snippet");

        await insertComment.ExecuteAsync();
    }
```

This is my Code to Insert a comment on a video of my choice.
What is wrong here? I got this code from another question on here and changed it a bit, but:

````
Error: Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
Request had insufficient authentication scopes. [403]
Errors [
        Message[Insufficient Permission] Location[ - ] Reason[insufficientPermissions] Domain[global]
]```
````

Comment: Seems that your problem is not your code but your permissions.

Comment: Well yea probably. Tho what should be wrong? I just took the OAuth2 id and key and used them what else am i gonna do lol

Answer (score 0):

According to the official doc of the [`CommentThreads.insert`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads/insert) API endpoint, a prerequisite of calling it is the following:

> [**Authorization**](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads/insert#auth)
>
> This request requires authorization with at least one of the following scopes ([read more about authentication and authorization](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication)).
>
> **Scope**
> `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl`

Therefore, your `youtubeService` should have been initialized by means of credentials obtained upon an OAuth 2.0 authentication/authorization flow and those credentials should have had attached among their scopes the one specified above.

Comment: Hi, i added the YoutubeService.Scopes.youtubeforcessl in my youtubeService object.

Comment: You mean `YoutubeService.Scopes.YoutubeForceSsl`, right?

Comment: yea didnt know the exact name lol, already tried to use the google auth cloud-plattforms link as well for the scopes. Im really lost

Comment: @Marvin Gornicec: But `YoutubeService.Scopes.YoutubeForceSsl` should work. If using it, what is the error message generated?

Comment: https://hatebin.com/uuoqbvpvuj Here is the code i still get the same error:

Error: Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
Request had insufficient authentication scopes. [403]
Errors [
        Message[Insufficient Permission] Location[ - ] Reason[insufficientPermissions] Domain[global]
]

Comment: @Marvin Gornicec: Try to run your code upon removing the line `commentThreadSnippet.ChannelId = "UCsK0terzCGmIPAeGmW-i-VA";`. I think this may confuse the endpoint, since you're specifying the video to which wanting to add a top-level comment just one source line below.

Comment: Its still not working after removing channelId, same error

Comment: @Marvin Gornicec: I'll suggest to post the entire exception stack trace obtained (post it as text within your question text above).